Upgraded useSWR from v1 to v2, data not returning when there's config/param
This is working fine when no config was included
const { data } = useSWR('/api/');

but once I added params, the data wont load
const config = {
  params: {
    param1: 'param1'
  }
}

const { data } = useSWR(['/api/', config]);


It used to work before, but once I upgraded from v1 to v2, everything is not loading anymore.
One of the attempt I made after reading the docs was this but I guess this is wrong
const { data } = useSWR({url:'/api/', args: {param1: 'param1'} });

PS: I have my fetcher set at global level
